# Role-playing Dimensions

Tags: sql-server, schema, date

I am new to data warehouse schema and i am confused about role-playing dimensions. i have searched a lot and regarding to dates in data warehouse, it is always the same type of example they give regarding to dates (order date key, ship date key, ship date key) in the fact table that links to a single date dimension.It makes sense, but in my schema (my schema is bigger but just an example) i have a login dimension (date,start time, end time,duration) that links to the "operator" dimension that links to the sales dimension. the fact_sales in my schema have dates which i assume are to be linked to date dimension (for example "sell date"), but what about the login dimension that have the login date? can i connect it to date dimensions directly or is not supposed to have a connection at all?

Comment: Could you provide some visuals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

role-playing dimensions are always related to the join between a fact and a dimension.
If you want to examine the login dates you have to place that filed in a fact and not in a dimension. So for example you could have a fact_login table with

- login_id
- datestart_id
- datestop_id

Here you have two IDs to link with the same dim_date, the first play the role of login start date, the second one as login end date...

Comment: ok thank you MBushi, i think i will do that. but what would be the difference  in ssas when choosing between having the login dimension as it is or create a fact_login table that connects to the date dimesion? for example  browing the cube  in ssas would there be any limitation by not having it as a fact table?

Comment: Sure, for example you can't count login by date. it's a matter of how you want to use a date. if you want to use it as an additional info of the login like name, surname and last login_date it's fine. but if you want to use aggregate functions like count you should place it in a fact table